# How to create dropdown list in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How to create the dropdown list in one to many relation. I want to populate the category data in Post form and then want to save using POST mode.
Here is my full code:

```
public class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            Posts = new Collection<Post>();

        }
        public int Id{get;set;}
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
public class Post
    {
        public int Id
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

PostFormVM:

```
public class PostFormVM
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }    
        public string Body { get; set; } 
        [Required]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }    
        public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }

}
```

Mapping is here:

```
public class ApplicationProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
    {
        public ApplicationProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Category, CategoryFormVM>().ReverseMap();
            CreateMap<Post, PostFormVM>().ReverseMap();
       }
   }
```

Generic Repository implementation

```
public class GenericRepository<T>:IGenericRepository<T> where T:class
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public GenericRepository(ApplicationDbContextcontext)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            return await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
        }
}
```

ICategoryRepository:

```
public interface ICategoryRepository:IGenericRepository<Category>
    {
    }
```

CategoryRepository implementation

```
public class CategoryRepository :GenericRepository<Category>, ICategoryRepository
    {
        public CategoryRepository(ApplicationDbContext context):base(context)
        {

        }
    }
```

PostRepo Implementation:

```
public class PostRepository : GenericRepository<Post>, IPostRepository
{
    public PostRepository(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
    {

    }
}
```

PostController:

```
public class PostItemController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IPostRepository _postRepository;
        private readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository;

        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public PostItemController(IPostRepository postRepository, ICategoryRepository categoryRepository, IMapper mapper, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
           _postRepository = postRepository;
            _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
           _userManager = userManager;
           _mapper = mapper;
        }


        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            //Here I want to populate the category data I have used the ViewBag and ViewData here
            //I am unable to get the data from the database
            ViewBag.Categories= _categoryRepository.GetAllAsync();

            return View(new PostFormVM());

        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(PostFormVM viewModel)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    return View("Create", viewModel);

                if (ModelState.IsValid) {

                    //Here I also want to map the selected category item and save to Post table. 
                    var post = _mapper.Map<Post>(viewModel);
                    post.ApplicationUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);

                    if (viewModel.IsEdit.Equals("false"))
                    {
                        await _postRepository.CreateAsync(post);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _postRepository.UpdateAsync(post);
                    }
                }             

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

I want help to populate the category data in Post Entity Create form.

Comment: What's the code of  `ICategoryRepository` and the Implementation of the relevant methods in `CategoryRepository ` ?

Comment: @XueliChen I have used generic implementation. You can see above.

Comment: Try to make `Create()` `asnyc` and then `await GetAllAsync`.

Comment: @JanWichelmann How can I make Create() async? I didn't get your clue.

Comment: Just add `asnyc Task<...>`, exactly as in your other `Create` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a breakpoint on this line `ViewBag.Categories = _categoryRepository.GetAllAsync();`, you can see such a result prompt `Result =" {Not yet computed} "`, because the method in your generic repository uses the await keyword to operate Asynchronous method, it will wait for the end of the previous process before calculating the result.

Try change you code in Generic Repository like below:

```
public List<T> GetAllAsync()
{
     return  _context.Set<T>().ToList();
}
```

IGenericRepository

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    List<T> GetAllAsync();
}
```

Show the Category list ,controller

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
       IEnumerable<Category> categories = _categoryRepository.GetAllAsync();
       ViewBag.Categories = categories;

       return View(new PostFormVM());
}
```

View

```
<select asp-for="CategoryId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Categories,"Id","Title"))"></select>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: This will produce a warning, since you do not have any await in an async method.

Comment: @Xueli Chen How can I convert ViewBag.Categories to IEnumerable?

Comment: I get the `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` error.